# How do you attach a controller MEAN.IO home route

Tags: angularjs, mean.io

The MEAN.IO route for home is controlled by the `viewPathProvider`. In the MEAN.IO docs they say that you can overload the home page by overloading the `viewPathProvider` config in your module.

```
angular.module('custom-package')
.config(['$viewPathProvider', function($viewPathProvider) {
         $viewPathProvider.override('system/views/index.html', 'custom-path');
}]);
```

However its not specified how to add an (AngularJS) controller to the view that is being loaded or how to associate a controller to it.

**Hint** in the system route there is a route where you can specify a controller but I would rather do this from my own package

```
    //Line 49 In system.js under system/public/routes 
    $meanStateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'system/views/index.html'
  //I can add a controller here but it will be stuck in the system package
  });
```

I also don't want to specify the controller in the HTML as most of my application is built with controllers specified in the route

Comment: found the answer for this?

Comment: No, I never did. The only option that I found is to update the system routes . But it definitely does not feel nice to mess with the core modules